# angular JS 2 app giving main.js not found error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using quickstart example for typescript from here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html, I have created exact structure and updated node_modules on server exactly the way they have it on Plunkr, when i am trying to run it from browser it gives main.js not found error, 
[image]

I have tried changing the path of main.ts in system config json file as well but no avail. I have enabled compile typescript in browser option.

I am running this on a apache2 server run on CentOS7

Comment: I think you are not running application with `npm start` because if you run application with it then this error will not come i think. up to which steps you have followed from documentation after which step you get this error ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 i want to run it with apache so that i know how to configure it on production server , I dont want nom server.

Comment: @ranakrunal9 it runs with nom server , but thats not my interest.